# Rack enclosure dimensions

Tags: rack, rackmount

We noticed that rack enclosures have different depths (600, 800, 1000 mm) while the DELL rack servers are 600 mm deep. In addition DELL rack enclosures are only 1000 mm deep.

Why should I purchase a rack enclosure 1000 mm deep for rack servers only 600 mm deep?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cable management arms and cables themselves need room too. Also, not all servers and devices are the same depth, so that explains the differences in enclosure depths.

Answer (score 2):

Because you need space for cables, etc.

Also your specific servers may be 600mm deep but Dell servers in general come in a variety of depths.

Answer (score 2):

What if you move to blades later, their enclosures are longer than 600mm usually.

Answer (score 1):

The extra space in back of the rack can be very nice for mounting "zero-U" PDUs in addition to giving you plenty of space for cable management. I've worked with many racks that were horribly under-sized for their contents, and it's *not* fun. I'd highly suggest you go with the 800mm at the least, if not the 1000mm..